# Getting the filename in the command parameter in context menu

Tags: java, windows, registry, contextmenu

Suppose my file `Test.java` is stored in : `X:\S\S\nOn I\Extra but Imp\Context Menu\Ultimate Windows Context Menu Customizer\`

I've created a context menu with command as `cmd /k javac -d . %1`

The output shows long file name with the path in which there are spaces.

What i want to do is directly compile a java file from context menu from command like :

`>javac -d . Test.java`
 I'am not able to get this as the `%1` returns the full path of file.

How can i do this ?? my folders are having spaces in there names.

I've tried to search many sites...

Answer (score 1):

You need to surround your argument with double-quotes and you don't need the `cmd /k` as far as I can tell:

```
javac -d . "%1"
```

However the Java compiler will error as you need to match the directory path it was invoked from with the package defined in the Java source.

You need to look into `Ant` or `Maven` to control your compilations.